# Making old Xcode project iPhone 6/6+ compatible

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcasset, uilaunchimagefile

I have an old project that shows is Xcode 3.2 compatible. I have manually created entries for app icon files in the info.plist. I try adding images.xcassets using File->New->File->iOS->User Interface but there is no option to add asset catalog. If I could add asset catalog (images.xcassets), it is straightforward to drag all the launch images and icons to support iPhone 6+. What do I do to add images.xcassets ? If this is not possible, how do I manually specify launch images in info.plist for 4.7 inch & 5.5 inch ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the path New File->Resource->Asset catalog